# How to decrease the thickness of lines in body content of pdf report

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, wicked-pdf

When I am going to generate the pdf report the lines in the content of pdf report appear thicker than they actually appear in editor. How to decrease the thickness or how to make them to look as it is in editor. I am using tinymce editor and wickedpdf gem to generate pdf report.

my css code for the body of the pdf report is

```
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure that the thickness of the lines in the PDF isn't a rendering side effect of an oddly zoomed percentage? Have you tried printing it out or changing the zoom on the PDF to see if that changes the appearance of the thickness?

Comment: No. the pdf rendered is not zoomed. it is the actual size of the report.but the thickness of lines changes on zooming in and out.